# how to browse and display image in html5 without using another language thing?

Tags: html

I have this HTML code to browse image

```
<input type="file" name="image" id="img>.
```

How can I display the image directely after browsing without using javascript or anyother thing?

Comment: Please add more information on what exactly you expect to change..

Answer (score 2):

No. You have to use JavaScript at least: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications#Example.3a.c2.a0Showing_thumbnails_of_user-selected_images

Comment: Even with a source. I can't think of a better answer, except for a standard change, adding a `<thumbnail input="" />` tag.